# How to remove Link And Scripts Element Dynamically

Tags: javascript, css

Suppose I have a web http://mayxaydungchina.com whose body contents can be dynamically populated using ajax or the `Load()` method.

How do I remove an existing  to an external css file or an external `<script>`  file from the head section of my web page?

I thought about using the append and prepend methods but I was thinking that they do not remove the existing link to an external css or an external script file.

I need to remove existing external css and scripts before adding new ones to help make my page load faster.

Comment: `document.scripts[Index].removeChild()`?

Comment: Not clear exactly what you want.. You want to remove existing script and load a new one ?

Comment: What will removing the script accomplish? It has already executed.